# ImportError: cannot import name '_has_torch_function' from 'torch._C'

Tags: python, pytorch, importerror

When I import `torch`, I get the following error:
I dont know if it has something to do with the fact i just install cuda11.6.
I tried to unintalled and install pytorch , it didn't work.

```
Python 3.7.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 26 2021, 06:08:21) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/zengyunzi1/.conda/envs/yz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 603, in <module>
  from ._tensor import Tensor
File "/home/zengyunzi1/.conda/envs/yz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 15, in <module>
  from torch.overrides import (
File "/home/zengyunzi1/.conda/envs/yz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/overrides.py", line 33, in <module>
  from torch._C import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_has_torch_function' from 'torch._C' (/home/zengyunzi1/.conda/envs/yz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
>>>
```

Comment: Maybe you have missing dependencies. Can you try to locate the file `/home/zengyunzi1/.conda/envs/yz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`? Does it exist?

Comment: HI, I checked, /home/zengyunzi1/.conda/envs/yz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so dose exist